# Javascript: Is Object an Array of Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Today I have a problem. I have a HTML Form, which can have a dynamic number of HTML Input Fields for an EMail Address. Via Javascript I want to evaluate those Data ans Post via XMLHttpRequest.

I fetch the Input fields like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementById("emailmodal").elements["multiple[]"];
```

Then I want to check, if it is an array, because if I have only one input field elements will not contain an array of elements, but only one element:

```
if(jQuery.isArray(elements))
{

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {

        formData.append("emailreceiver[]", elements[i].value);

    }

}else
{

    formData.append("emailreceiver[]", elements.value);

}
```

In case it is an Array, it is going through the Elements via For Loop, and if not, its directly taking the value.

However this doesnt work correctly. Even if I have multiple INputs, the Script tells me, its no array.

The Corresponding HTML is

```html
<div class="form-group input-group">
<input type="text" name="multiple[]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $kundendaten['Email']; ?>">
<span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-add">+</button></span>
</div>
```

This is from Bootstrap.

If i make var log to console and I have more then one element than it looks like this:
[image]

If I make var log and only have one element it looks like this

[image]

What can I do?

Cheers,
Niklas

Comment: Yes object is also an array of elements in JS because Javascript does'nt support associative arrays.

Comment: DOM Element doesn't have `elements` method. Can you share the output of elements ?

Comment: can't you just depend on the object length and if the length is greater than one, treat the object like an array?

Comment: I uploaded some pictures of var log.

Comment: I agree with @Mmcgowa3 you can easily just use `$("form input.email").length` and check if you have more than one input. Also you can keep a counter with a global variable and update it in the same function that adds additional input elements to your form

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Mmcgowa!!

```
if(elements.length > 1)
{

    alert("Array");
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {

        formData.append("emailreceiver[]", elements[i].value);

    }

}else
{

    alert("No Array");
    formData.append("emailreceiver[]", elements.value);

}
```

This works. If elements is no array, element.length will be undefined!

Answer (score 0):

I know you already have a solution, but why don't you simplify your code flow and do the following:

```
if (elements.length == 1) elements = [elements];

// now you know that if *elements* is not empty, it is always an array
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    formData.append("emailreceiver[]", elements[i].value);
}
```